# Store event listeners from a dom element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, clone

Is it possible to store all event listeners from an element in order to retrieve it after cloning an element?

```
//clone element makes event listeners stripped
var old_element=document.getElementById('dhtml_menu-1895');     
// var el= alleventlistenersfrom this element
var new_element = old_element.cloneNode(true);  
old_element.parentNode.replaceChild(new_element, old_element);  

 //some event actions 

 //give back original event listeners
```

Comment: I suppose to answer this question more info is needed. If you are cloning the element to specifically remove event listeners why do you need to add them back? Also in your code above, what happens between cloning to remove events and adding them back? Feels like some odd design choices but without more info its hard to say.

Comment: i want to save the dhtml_menu-1895 class in the session storage on-click to keep a memory of collapsed/expanded li but the dhtml module already have a prototype on-click event on this element so it does not work without stripping. if i strip though, i lost the nested dhtml menu behaviour so i'd need to put it back after do the session storage

Comment: perhaps if you update the question showing your html, the events attached to each piece of the html, what you are specifically trying to store in session storage, which event you are trying to remove and which element and the event you are trying to retain someone could be of more help. As of now I just feel there are too many different pieces of this problem we are unaware of to help you find a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think the real solution to your problem is to bind your event to an element higher up on the DOM that way you don't have to dynamically bind events when elements are created.

So I'm assuming you have something like this:

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='element-to-replace'></div>
</div>
```

And you are changing out the `.element-to-replace` in your code somewhere, but you have event listeners on it like so:

```
document.querySelector('.element-to-replace').addEventListener('click', doSomething);
```

In that situation, you should bind to the parent element since it will never change and target your child element.

```
document.querySelector('.parent').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  if (evt.target.className.includes('element-to-replace'))
    doSomething();
});
```

You can do that or abstract out the creation of those new elements and place your event binding code in the function block.